# How to restrict entity reference displaying values?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a requirement which I feel quiet complex. I am using Entity reference in X content type to reference a content type(assume Y). This works fine by displaying all the values of Y in X. 
  Y content type is having one field that is true or false type. So I want to display values in select list of X content type only which is having true value in the Y content type.So how can I achieve that, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: answer this two questions : 

1 .where do you want  achieve this ? in node full view mode? in views ? where?

2.   you want if boolean field of content type Y is true  show  entity_referece field ( I mean a field that is in X content type) ?

Comment: @zhilevan , 1. I want to achieve this in admin panel only may be that is only called as node full view mode. 2) Actually that is a text field only,but while adding content we will write true or false

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to dynamically create that select list based on the field's values which are `TRUE` from the CT Y. I suppose that this select list belongs to a from, and what a convenient hook [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) is!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_xyz_form_id') {
    // Find all referenced items
    $target_ids = $form['field_reference_to_ct_y'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#options'];
    // Load all referenced items
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($target_ids));
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      if ($node->field_to_check_if_true[LANGUAGE_NODE][0]['value']) {
         // Alter the select list options
         $form[field_select_list][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options'][$node->nid] = $node->title;
       }
    }
  }
}
```